# Dynamic layout in CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have made a very simple layout in CSS in ASP.net.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<h1> Site
</div>

<div id="section">
<h1>Content</h1>
 </div>

<div id="footer">
Footer
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
}
#section {
    text-align:center;
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;      
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptgcfgks/)

What I want is that if I change the size of footer,header or content area in my design view of ASP.net designer all other areas resize themselves accordingly.
that is increasing or decreasing any section has cascading effect on all other areas.
**For example if I increase the size of footer then size of content and header should make their size at par with the footer.**
How this could be done?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Define "resize themselves accordingly".

Comment: I gave a example plz read that.

Comment: You will need to give widths in percentages than fixed widths.

Comment: @khan for that you need to give width in percentage. which is already works in your demo. if you have fixed width then you can make changes using JQuery on resize event.

Comment: @ketan jquery stuff would work fine but can u share a link with me?

Comment: @khan you can check it here. http://jsfiddle.net/yMcXm/210/

Comment: @khan Check the answer i have given below.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want a responsive design? I have added a wrapper div around your contents, when you increase the width of that, width of other elements will also get increased as the width is given in percentage. Please see fiddle for more details https://jsfiddle.net/ptgcfgks/1/

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<h1> Site
</div>

<div id="section">
<h1>Content</h1>
 </div>

<div id="footer">
Footer
</div>

 </div><!--wrapper-->
```